# iOS Storyboard clobbering variables when pushing scenes? Why? How should it be done?

Tags: ios, storyboard, segue, corruption

I have the following storyboard configuration in my iOS project.

storyboard1->NavController-sceneA->stoyboard2/initialview

storyboard2->sceneB->sceneC

-> is a "show" segue
Scene A loads a storyboard and pushes it onto its navigation controller.

- Scene A has a controller that instances class X.
- Scene B uses the default UIViewControoler Class.
- SceneC has a controller that
  instances class Y.

The implementations for both classes are as follows

```
//ClassX.h//
@interface ClassX : UITableViewController

//ClassX.m//
@implementation ClassX
NSArray* model;

//..
@end


//ClassY.h//
@interface ClassY : UITableViewController

//ClassY.m//
@implementation ClassY
NSArray* model;

//..
@end
```

The problem is that when I try to load scene C, it tries to use the field called "model" in its implementation– but gets the field of the model for scene A for some reason.  Why is this and how should I correct it?

Comment: It's an example, I'll fix it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should make model a property of the classes rather than declaring them as you do. They are probably creating global variables. Or declare them inside {} after @implementation to make sure they are variables which are part of the class.

So either:

```
@implementation{
  NSArray *model
}
...
@end
```

or better use private properties and use self.model in the code.:

So in classY.m try:

```
@interface ClassY ()
   @property NSArray *model;
@end

@implementation ClassY
...
@end
```

Do the same for ClassX.

Comment: So a property is private as long as it doesn't appear in an interface block?  and I was missing curly braces for a private variable, so I got a global instead?  Is that correct?  Although yes strictly speaking Objective C doesn't have private things, if you know its name you can use it.

Comment: It is common to add properties you want to be hidden from the .h (so private to the .m) to use an extension with () declared as an interface in the .m file. ivars for a class have to be in {}s after the @implementation.

Comment: Ok I misunderstood variable scope, and was creating a program global, this makes sense now.

Comment: Very easily done, even if you know where it should be. I always use properties now and never use {}s.